# ¿Cual es el tercer parámetro de la función sort de la Standard Library?

Tags: c++

Sort pide tres parámetros, el primero es el inicio del conjunto de elementos a ordenar, el segundo es el final, pero el tercero no se lo que es. He intentado mirarlo en la documentación, pero no lo entiendo. ¿Que es, pues, el tercer parámetro necesario para usar sort?¿Que espera?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añado código.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::sort;


int main()
{
    vector<double> temps;
    double distancetemp{ 0 }, distancetotal{0};

    //introduccion de valores en el vector, si valor es distinto de double, termina el while

    while (cin >> distancetemp)
    {
        //if (distancetemp != (double)distancetemp) break;
        //else
        temps.push_back(distancetemp);
    }

    //recorrer vector y sumar valor de elementos.

    for (double x : temps) { distancetotal += x; }
    cout << "Distancia total recorrida: " << distancetotal << '\n';

    //ordenamos el vector para encontrar su menor valor y el mayor
    sort(temps.begin, temps.end);
    cout << "Distancia menor recorrida: " << temps[0] << '\n';
    cout << "Distancia mayor recorrida: " << temps[temps.size() - 1] << '\n';
    cout << "La media de las distancias entre ciudades vecinas es: " << distancetotal / temps.size() << '\n';

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Añadido. La lógica puede estar mal.

Answer (score 3):

La función `std::sort` tiene 4 sobrecargas:

```
template< class RandomIt >
void sort( RandomIt, RandomIt );
```

Ordena los datos entre los [iteradores de acceso aleatorio](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) proveídos.

```
template< class ExecutionPolicy, class RandomIt >
void sort( ExecutionPolicy&&, RandomIt, RandomIt );
```

Disponible de C++17 en adelante, usa una [política de ejecución](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) para realizar la ordenación entre los iteradores de acceso aleatorio proveídos.

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt, RandomIt, Compare );
```

Ordena los datos entre los iteradores de acceso aleatorio proveídos usando un funtor para hacer la comparación entre elementos.

```
template< class ExecutionPolicy, class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( ExecutionPolicy&&, RandomIt, RandomIt, Compare );
```

Usa una política de ejecución para ordenar los datos entre los iteradores de acceso aleatorio proveídos usando un funtor para hacer la comparación entre elementos.

---

Sospecho que en tu caso falla porque no puede deducir los iteradores de la versión de dos parámetros e ignora la llamada:

```
sort(temps.begin, temps.end);
```

Posiblemente sea porque faltan los paréntesis:

```
sort(temps.begin(), temps.end());
//              ~~           ~~
```

Comment: Madre mia, solo cometo fallos tontos. Que vergüenza.

Comment: @Gojira son fallos que se cometen al aprender... C++ tiene mucha chicha